# value of $g$ in $G=\nabla g.$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> If $G(x,y)=(xy+y^2)\vec{i}+(x^5+2xy)\hat{j}.$ Then find function  $g$ for which $G=\nabla g.$

What i try

$$(xy+y^2)\vec{i}+(x^5+2xy)\hat{j}=\frac{dg}{dx}\hat{i}+\frac{dg}{dy}\hat{k}$$

$$\displaystyle \frac{dg}{dx}=xy+y^2\Longrightarrow g=\frac{x^2}{2}y+xy+C_{1}\cdots (1)$$

$$\frac{dg}{dy}=x^5+2xy\Longrightarrow g=x^5y+xy^2+C_{2}\cdots (2)$$

Now How can i find $C_{1},C_{2}$ such that i have get same value of $g$ for $(1)$ and $(2)$

Help me please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your vector-field does not have a potential, because it's curl is non-zero:
$$\frac{\partial G_2}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial G_1}{\partial y} = y-2x \neq 0$$
But in general, you would want to solve only one of the differential equations, for example
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}=u(x, y) \implies g(x, y) = \int u(x, y) \mathrm{d}x + C(y)$$
(Note that the constant depends on the $y$ here!)

And subsitute this into the other differential equation, to solve for $C(y)$.

To demonstrate it, I will show a simple example:

$$G(x,y)=(2x, 2y)$$
Then we need to have that
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} = 2x \implies g(x, y)=\int 2x \mathrm{d}x+C(y)=x^2+C(y)$$
And
$$2y=\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}=C'(y) \implies C(y)=y^2 + c$$
Which implies that
$$g(x)=x^2+y^2+c$$